# How to change value of radio button array in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

There is a radio button field, which needs to be updated as the index changes.

```
<input type="radio" class="validate[required]" name="status_check[]" id="status_check" value="'+k+'">
```

`k` is a JavaScript variable which is updated each time an image is appended

`status_check` is an array and more values are added in it by appending html as they are used with images which are appended as well. When one of the image among the appended images is deleted we need to update the value for some of the indexes of the `status_check` array in JavaScript. We are using the below code to update the values but it's not working

```
document.getElementsById("status_check").childnode[i].value
```

where `i` is the index.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
i = 5;
$("#status_check:eq("+i+")").val(val);
```

This would select 6th #status_check. Is this what you need?

`:eq()` is an index selector, that means that it selects n-th element (0 indexed) from matched list. More at http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

`val` is the value which you need to set.

Comment: what is eq here ? and val is the value which we have to pass?

Comment: var checkVal = new Array();
  checkVal = document.getElementsByName("status_check[]");
  var checkLength = checkVal.length;
  for(var i=idVal; i <= checkLength; i++)
  {
   var newValue = parseInt(checkVal[i].value)-1;
   
   $("#status_check:eq("+i+")").val(newValue);
  }
This is the code and its not working.

Comment: why aren't you simply using `checkVal[i].value = newValue;` ?

Comment: Got my problem solved with checkVal[i].value = newValue. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery code

```
var index = 2;

$.each($('[name^=status_check]'), function (i, item) {
    if(i == index)
    {
        $(this).val("some value");
    }
});
```